# apply css to Js strings-Js/CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to show tooltip on hover using data-tip attribute. HOwever since data-tip attribute just accepts strings. I couldnt use HTML and now I have settled with the following approach.

```
var title = "Hello World";
var online: "Last Online 2 mins ago".
    <div>
        <span data-tip={title +" \n " +online} data-tip-always>{title}</span>
    </div>
```

However now Im stuck at a point where how can I make `{title}` bold and `{online}` font-size to smaller than the `{title}`

with this code:

```
const titles = `<span class="title">Hello</span>`;
const online = `<span class="online">You are online</span>` ;
<span data-tip={`${titles}\n${online}`} data-html="true" data-tip-always>{title}</span>
```

I get this:
[image]

initially I wanted to have this in the form of jsx so that I can add colors and fonts to it, however I couldn't find a way to use jsx/html inside a `data-tip` 
Is there any way I can apply css to strings?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using react-tooltip?

Comment: not really, this would html5 data-tip attribute

Comment: How are you showing the tooltip? `data-tip` doesn't do anything by itself; it's just a data attribute.

Comment: @AuxTaco: you;re right, its the react-tooltip and my bad I wasn't aware of this. I'm not really a html/css/react guy.. thanks for catching this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React-tooltip's `data-tip` only accepts strings, but [`data-for` can point to a `<ReactTooltip>` that can contain anything](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip#using-react-component-as-tooltip):

```js
var title = 'Hello World';
var online = 'Last Online 2 mins ago';

ReactDOM.render(
<div>
  <span data-tip data-for="unique-tooltip-id" data-tip-always>{title}</span>
  <ReactTooltip id="unique-tooltip-id">
    <div className="tooltip-title">{title}</div>
    <div className="tooltip-online">{online}</div>
  </ReactTooltip>
</div>,
document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.tooltip-title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tooltip-online {
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/wwayne/react-tooltip@master/standalone/react-tooltip.min.js"></script>

<div id="react" style="position:absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);"></div>
```

<sup>the snippet only works in "full page" for some reason</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can make that be a template string (notice es6 notation)

Variables being:

```
const title = `<span class="title">Hello</span>`
const online = `<span class="online">You are online</span>`
```

And code being:

```
<div>
   <span data-tip={`${title}\n${online}`} data-tip-always>{title}</span>
</div>
```

In which you can interpolate whatever you want as variables inside the string and then have the advantage of take it from the `Element.dataset`.

Comment: but hie can I add classes to these variables unless I have html selectors present?

Comment: Updated my answer, you can do the above if you want to go the vanilla js way, but if you are using react why not to use it all power. You will then need to create a `<Tooltip>` component that receives the content (also JSX) as its children.

Comment: this is what I did: ```  const titles = `<span class="title">Hello</span>`;
    const online = `<span class="online">You are online</span>` ;<span data-tip={`${titles}\n${online}`} data-html="true" data-tip-always>{title}</span>```, but the tooltip renders with the html tags :( - screenshot attached in the question.